# Issue with float datatype

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a radnumeric textbox with monthly salary as below.
txtMonthlySalary.Text=816177200
Now I need to calculate the annual salary and save it as a float variable in the sql server table.My table is already an existing one and the annual salary field is type float.

Actual calculation on Annual salary gives following result:
Annual salary = 816177200 * 12 = 9,794,126,400

But in the program,
float Fld_AnnualSalary = float.Parse(txtMonthlySalary.Text) * 12;
gives result as 9,794,127,000

Here float data type rounds the result it seems,which is a big variation from the actual expected result.
How can I handle this issue,so that I can get the exact result on multiplication without rounding and save it in a float variable in sql sever table.

Answer (score 4):

`float` and even `double` are not generally acceptable data types to work with real money values (as you just proved for yourself).

Please use `Decimal` in the code and corresponding type in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has a precision limited to about seven digits, and you are trying to do calculations on a nine-digit number `816177200`.

The anwer by Alexeis Levenkov contains the solution to your problem. The [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) data type can hold at least 28 significant digits.